# How does my ASP.NET app "know" when code is changed?

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis

I've recently become stuck on very weird and frustrating problem which started when I changed my **ASP.NET** application from **IIS Express** to **IIS Local**.

The database used to populate fine, but now it only does whenever I make a change to the code and run. It doesn't matter *what* changes I make - I can even insert a white space and it will work after I hit run. But then if I run *again* it won't work. It only works when you make a change and compile.

From what I gather the problem looks like something to do with my database connection being fussy about caching. But I disabled caching in both IIS and the web.config and I'm still getting the same behaviour.

Does anyone have a theory of what's going on? I guess my basic questions are these:

(1) How does the app "know" when the code is changed? What is changing about the state of the program to produce the different behaviour?

(2) Why did changing from IIS Express to IIS Local (same IP is being used to retrieve data) result in this thing happening?

(3) Is there any way I can reproduce or simulate the original behaviour within IIS Local?

Comment: are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: No. Although not sure I understand the relevance of the question ...

Comment: Check expiration time for the cache used. You might be getting stale data due to longer duration of cache. ASP.NET can remove data from the cache:
Because memory on the server is low, a process known as scavenging,
Because the item in the cache has expired, or
Because the item's dependency changes.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597(v=vs.100).aspx
Considering your scenario, you can try SqlCacheDependency to update cache whenever the data gets updated. Here's a helpful link: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/caching-data/using-sql-cache-dependencies-cs

Comment: Thanks, I will be more vigilant about that (although I have tried changing cache duration). I'm using Couchbase database which makes things more difficult. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this problem by remembering to close the Couchbase data cluster when the application closed.